# regular expression to return the uppercase message in parenthesis, after the process id

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want the `extract_pid` function to return the uppercase message in parenthesis, after the process id.
Following code is printing `pid`s but not sure how to add capital letters in parenthesis:

```
def extract_pid(log_line):
  regex = r"\[(\d+)\]+[A-Z]"
  result = re.search(regex, log_line)
  if result is None:
    return None
  return "{} ({})".format(result[1], result)
```

For example:

```
print(extract_pid("July 31 07:51:48 mycomputer bad_process[12345]: ERROR Performing package upgrade"))
```

and output would be:

```
12345 (ERROR)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
def extract_pid(log_line):
    regex = r"\[(\d+)\]\: ([A-Z]*)"
    result = re.search(regex, log_line)
    if result is None:
        return None
    return "{} ({})".format(result[1],result[2])
```

Comment: Note: @nino_701 kindly edited your post to improve the formatting and make it more readable. Please be sure to review their edit to see how they accomplished that so you can format code in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

If we want only upper case after :(colon)

```
regex = r"\[(\d+)\]\: ([A-Z]+)"
```

Comment: This appears to be the best proposed regular expression for the original question (the answer by Ishant Kumar would yield content with empty parentheses for lines without an uppercase message, and the one by Edgar Suhr just takes the first word, uppercase or not). Some context and execution examples would be beneficial, but in principle, it should be possible to insert this regex definition into any of the mentioned answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved. I did struggle though.

```
import re
def extract_pid(log_line):
    regex = r"\[(\d+)\]\: (\w+)"
    result = re.search(regex, log_line)
    if result is None:
        return None
    return "{} ({})".format(result[1], result[2])

print(extract_pid("July 31 07:51:48 mycomputer bad_process[12345]: ERROR Performing package upgrade")) # 12345 (ERROR)
print(extract_pid("99 elephants in a [cage]")) # None
print(extract_pid("A string that also has numbers [34567] but no uppercase message")) # None
print(extract_pid("July 31 08:08:08 mycomputer new_process[67890]: RUNNING Performing backup")) # 67890 (RUNNING)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct Regex expression is :

```
r"\[(\d+)\]\: ([A-Z]+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def extract_pid(log_line):
    regex = r"\[(\d+)\]:\s\b([A-Z]*)\b"
    result = re.search(regex, log_line)
    if result is None:
        return None
    return "{} ({})".format(result[1], (result[2]))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found as follows:

```
import re
def extract_pid(log_line):
regex = r"\[(\d+)\]:\s([A-Z]*)\s"
result = re.search(regex, log_line)
if result is None:
    return None
return "{} ({}) ".format(result[1],result[2])

print(extract_pid("July 31 07:51:48 mycomputer bad_process[12345]: ERROR 
Performing package upgrade")) # 12345 (ERROR)
print(extract_pid("99 elephants in a [cage]")) # None
print(extract_pid("A string that also has numbers [34567] but no uppercase 
message")) # None
print(extract_pid("July 31 08:08:08 mycomputer new_process[67890]: RUNNING 
Performing backup")) # 67890 (RUNNING)
```

And The output is :
12345 (ERROR)
None
None
67890 (RUNNING)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
def extract_pid(log_line):
    regex = r"\[(\d+)\]\:\s\b([A-Z]*\b)" #using word boundaries makes the search case sensitive in the event our result has a mix of both lower & uppercase letters.
    result = re.search(regex, log_line)
    if result is None:
        return None
    return "{} ({})".format(result[1], result[2])
```

Comment: In the event we have e.g. ERror then RE won't be matching the subject string but without word boundaries it becomes case insensitive the RE is greedy and matches the subject string.